# Hide wowza overlay after an interval of time

Tags: wowza

I am using Wowza Media Streams for a live streaming in my project. I am using overlay on video. My question is, that I want to hide displaying overlay after an interval of time. Please guide me is there any way to do this. My code is for using overlay is

```
wowzaImage = new OverlayImage(basePath+"logo_14.png",100);
mainImage.addOverlayImage(wowzaImage,srcWidth-wowzaImage.GetWidth(1.0),0);
```

This is being used to display overlay. To Hide this overlay after fix time, I tried this

```
mainImage.addOverlayImage(null,srcWidth-wowzaImage.GetWidth(1.0),0);
```

But this didn't work. Also tried

```
wowzaImage = new OverlayImage(basePath+"logo_14.png",0);
mainImage.addOverlayImage(wowzaImage,srcWidth-wowzaImage.GetWidth(1.0),0);
```

But it still shows overlay there. 
Please help, Thanks

Comment: I think can do this with [Clamp](https://streamtoolbox.com/clamp) directly. Try removing the previously added overlay image, don't just create a second new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at the example [here](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?432-How-to-add-graphic-overlays-to-live-streams-with-Wowza-Transcoder#fadelogo) you can find a couple of ways to accomplish this (depending on how you've set it up).  You can leverage the add fading step convenience function as follows:

```
mainImage.addFadingStep([start-value],[end-value],[number-of-frames]);
```

Otherwise you can fade the image itself away on each frame (see onBeforeScaleFrame event handler) similar to the way you were suggesting in your question:

```
OverlayImage img = new OverlayImage([resource], opacity);
mainImage.addOverlayImage(img,xpos, ypos);
```

For the latter you will want to be sure it is being referenced correctly and that the positioning holds true.

Thanks,

Matt